# How to add Android X.X in Project -> Properties -> Java BuildPath

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

I think the title is very clear. Sometimes I have some build errors, and in the `Libraries` tab of `Java Build Path`, I add/remove libraries, etc ... but when I delete the `Android X.X` "folder", I can't bring it back. What I do is to delete the project from the Workspace and `Import` it again as `Existing Android Project`.

1. Is there a way to add it directly without deleting-importing a project?
2. How does eclipse generate it? for what purpose? Why if missing eclipse doesn't show errors before building?

Please help me understand all these!

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: Thanks, your answers solves the issue. But can you answer the second question please ??

Comment: Yes sure.. Regarding second- I can't understand it clearly. `How does eclipse generate it ?` means you asking about the Android X.X folder

Comment: yes ! because everytime I had the issue, i delete it from workspace, and when importing it, eclipse automatically addes it to the project !

Comment: So you saying you don't want Android X.X foler in your project. To Build Android application you need Android SDK. Thats why eclipse automatically adds it to your project when you import it even though you delete it in workspace. As the project is created with Base Android Project

Comment: Sorry my last comment was not clear : 

`yes ! because everytime I had the issue, i delete the project from workspace, and when importing it, eclipse automatically addes Android X.X to the project !` - How does eclipse generate it ? for what purpose ? Why if missing eclipse doesn't show errors before building ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49645/discussion-between-vino-and-mansoulx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that without removing the project and importing it back.

***Right Click your Project-> Java Build Path->Add Library->Android Classpath Container->Choose your Project->Ok***

You will your Android X.X back.

Hope it helps.

Comment: nice ! answers the first question ? what about the second one ?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete your project click  on the check box which says Delete projects content on disk and then import your project and  to add library go to properties->java build path->order and export and check your library